# What should I look for to troubleshoot this model not rendering in the MVC DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page where I used this format::

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlAssignedPermissions", (Model.selLstPermissionsSource), null, new { @id = "ddlAssignedPermissions", @size = "10", @onchange = "UnAssignPermssion(this)" })
```

The first parameter is just the control name `ddlAssignedPermissions`.  The documentation says that first parameter is supposed to be some exposed property name of the actual selectedID.
But as you see here in this (WORKING) instance its just the control name.

I tried to follow my format on a new page with similar functionality and I can SEE the model content in the View in the debugger, but the model content doesn't render in the view

please what am I missing here

[IMG]http://s678.photobucket.com/user/christianprogrammer/media/Data.jpg.html][IMG]http://i678.photobucket.com/albums/vv149/christianprogrammer/Data.jpg[/IMG]

"http://s678.photobucket.com/user/christianprogrammer/media/Data.jpg.html" target="_blank">

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your drop down would work on one page and not the other.  Your drop down is formatted a little differently than how I do them so I thought I would share to see if something would help.  The first field is rendered as the ID of the drop down so you don't need to add the id in the html attributes.  I have found that if that field matches the name of one of the fields in your passed in model then it will get set to that value and the value of the drop down will post back.  Similar to a dropdownlistfor.  I have never put () around my select list so you might try removing them.  You don't need the null.  I have only found the need to put @ in front of an HTML attribute for class and style.  All of the other attributes you should be able to add without that.  The formats that I use for drop down list and drop down list for are

```
@Html.DropDownList("FieldName", Model.SelectList, new { @style = "", name = "Name" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FieldName, Model.SelectList, new { @class = "SelectList" })
```

Hopefully something here helps :)